# Objects whose tangent spaces are modules over noncommutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am interested in finding examples of geometric objects whose tangent spaces at a point have the structure of a module over some noncommutative ring. In algebraic geometry, there are well-known examples of objects such as abelian varieties or elliptic curves, whose tangent spaces are abelian groups. However, I want to generalize this property to other rings and modules.

More precisely, let $X$ be a geometric object, such as a scheme, a variety, a stack, or something else, and let $R$ be a noncommutative ring with identity. I want to find conditions on $X$ and $R$ such that for any point $x \in X$, the tangent space $T_x X$ is an $R$-module. Moreover, I want this module structure to be compatible with the geometric structure of $X$, in some sense.

For example, if $X$ is a scheme and $R$ is a commutative ring, then one possible condition is that $X$ is locally of finite type over $R$, and the module structure on $T_x X$ is induced by the cotangent sheaf $\Omega_{X/R}$. However, I do not know how to generalize this to the noncommutative case, or if there are other possible conditions.

I am looking for any insights or references on this problem

Comment: The tangent spaces for hyperkähler manifolds all have a natural quaternionic structure.